# joining a subquery with aggregate data

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I am having trouble combined two queries, using join/subquery.

My first query is pulling sales totals (this example pulls just one product):

```
SELECT
DAB020.ARTNR,
SUM(DAB020.RE_WERT) as "Total Euros",
COUNT(DISTINCT DAB020.ANUMMER) as "Number of Orders"
FROM "DAB020.ADT" DAB020
WHERE DAB020.RE_DATUM >= { d '2021-01-01' } AND DAB020.ARTNR = '123456'
GROUP BY DAB020.ARTNR
```

example results:

```
ARTNR   Total VK €  Auftrag Nr
123456  999999,50   60
```

works fine, giving for one article, the total sales this year + the unique number of order numbers.

My second query (coming from a different table), shows the number of sales offers made:

```
Select
COUNT(DISTINCT left (DAB055.APNUMMER,6)) as "# offers"
FROM "DAB055.ADT" DAB055
WHERE (DAB055.BUCH_DATUM>={d '2021-01-01'}) // YYYY.MM.DD
AND DAB055.ARTNR = '123456'
```

example results:

```
ARTNR   # offers
123456  120
```

also works fine, shows for the article number, the count of unqiue offer numbers.

Now I want to append the offer results, onto the end of the sales results:

```
SELECT
DAB020.ARTNR,
SUM(DAB020.RE_WERT) as "Total Euro",
COUNT(DISTINCT DAB020.ANUMMER) as"Number of Orders",

left join (
  Select
  COUNT(DISTINCT left (DAB055.APNUMMER,6)) as "# offers"
  FROM "DAB055.ADT" DAB055
  WHERE (DAB055.BUCH_DATUM>={d '2021-01-01'}) // YYYY.MM.DD
  ) as results on DAB055.ARTNR = DAB020.ARTNR

FROM "DAB020.ADT" DAB020
WHERE DAB020.RE_DATUM >= { d '2021-01-01' } AND DAB020.ARTNR = '969226'
GROUP BY DAB020.ARTNR
```

desired results:

```
ARTNR   Total VK €  Auftrag Nr  # offers
123456  999999,50   60          120
```

but it doesn't work of course. The link between the two tables is DAB055.ARTNR and DAB020.ARTNR, but I am not sure how to get the syntax correct.

Can somone clarify my mistake?
Thanks!

EDIT: just a note - im using only one article here for testing. For the final query, it will be a few hundred.

Comment: Perhaps show a small mock-up example of input and output data.

Comment: "append onto the end of" & "it doesn't work" are not clear. So it's not clear how you want output to be a function of input. [mre] [ask]

Comment: hi, i've updated with some examples of the results and expected results. Currently, when running the query, I get the message "Expected lexical element not found: identifier or expression".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is only doing a single product, you can just do each query as a from alias.  Since each returns a single row, it will be 1:1 and pull values directly.  I still have the key ID in each respectively to accommodate final join.  However, if you wanted other `ARTNR` values, or ALL `ARTNR` for the date time range in question, just remove the single `ARTNR` from each subquery respectively in the where clauses.  Then you can get all offers with orders and euro counts/totals.

```
SELECT
        Q1.ARTNR,
        Q1.TotalEuro "Total Euro",
        Q1.NumberOfOrders "Number of Orders",
        Q2.NumberOffers "# Offers"
    from
        ( SELECT
                DAB020.ARTNR,
                SUM(DAB020.RE_WERT) as TotalEuro,
                COUNT(DISTINCT DAB020.ANUMMER) as NumberofOrders,
            FROM 
                "DAB020.ADT" DAB020
            WHERE 
                    DAB020.RE_DATUM >= { d '2021-01-01' } 
                AND DAB020.ARTNR = '969226'
            GROUP BY 
                DAB020.ARTNR ) Q1
    JOIN
        ( Select
                DAB055.ARTNR,
                COUNT(DISTINCT left (DAB055.APNUMMER,6)) as NumberOffers
            FROM 
                "DAB055.ADT" DAB055
            WHERE 
                    DAB055.BUCH_DATUM >= { d '2021-01-01'}
                AND DAB055.ARTNR = '969226'
            GROUP BY
                DAB055.ARTNR ) Q2
         on Q1.ARTNR = Q2.ARTNR
```